# Is anyone else having trouble adding/removing tags to questions?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tagging, design, editor

Normally you just start typing and after a few characters it autocompletes and you can see the suggestions. But now I can't see the drop-down bar. Anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: Like, the 'bar' pops down but I can't see any of the suggestions. Wish I could screenshot.

Comment: Yes, i do have the same situation

Comment: Seems to be known and network-wide: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353785/tag-suggestions-are-empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be fixed now, at least for me!

Comment: The question on Meta SE is marked status-completed, so I think we're probably good.